# How to add jar operation using ant

Tags: java, apache, jar, ant

I am trying to run a jar file and execute some unit tests. Currently (without ant) I do it like this

```
java -jar ./rest-test-runner-0.0-all.jar run HelpServiceUrlTest -config ./tools/rest-test-config/srv13/
```

That would run me a test class that was specified. How can I do exactly the same (or run all tests) using ant ?

I have this so far. It starts and ends with success but does not execute any test

```
<target name="run-tests" depends="prepare">
<java jar="rest-test-runner-0.0-all.jar"
  fork="true"
  failonerror="true"
  maxmemory="128m">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="rest-test-runner-0.0-all.jar"/>
        <pathelement path="${java.class.path}"/>
    </classpath>
    <jvmarg value="-Dconfig=srv10"/>
</java>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet will do exactly the same as the command line you provided

```
<target name="run-tests" depends="prepare">
<java jar="rest-test-runner-0.0-all.jar"
  fork="true"
  failonerror="true"
  maxmemory="128m">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="rest-test-runner-0.0-all.jar"/>
        <pathelement path="${java.class.path}"/>
    </classpath>
    <arg line="run HelpServiceUrlTest -config ./tools/rest-test-config/srv13/"/>
</java>
```

Comment: It was exactly what I needed. Do you think it would be possible to provide this test name as an argument to the "ant test" command ? So that I can say from the outside which test to run ?

Comment: Yes you can use `<arg line="run ${unittestcase} -config ./tools/rest-test-config/srv13/"/>` and then run `ant test -Dunittestcase=HelpServiceUrlTest`